# How to import a custom java.awt.Font from a Font family with multiple TTF files? (An example is included)

Tags: java, fonts, import, awt

I know that you can import a Font in Java with something like this:

```
File file = new File(fontPath);
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, file);
// alternative:
// Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new FileInputStream(file));
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);
```

Then you would use for example `font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);` to get the desired style and size.

---

**Example**

But now let's look as an example at the font `Consolas`, there you have four TTF files:

- `consola.ttf` (Plain)
- `consolab.ttf` (Bold)
- `consolai.ttf` (Italic)
- `consolaz.ttf` (Bold & Italic)

Of course you could just import `consola.ttf` with the method stated above, but then using `font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 20);` isn't the same as using `consolab.ttf` because the plain font was simply transformed to *look like* a bold font.

---

**Example Pictures**

1. Here I used the installed font with `new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 20);` and `new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 20);` (as a side note, if the font is installed on the system you also get the right bold font if you use `deriveFont(Font.BOLD);`):

[image: Using the installed TTF Fonts]

2. And this is `consola.ttf`, imported with `createFont` and derived bold font (both with size 20 like the example above):

[image: Using the imported TTF with derived bold Font]

---

Well when installed it isn't a problem, but I don't expect others to have a custom Font, so I want to put the TTFs into the jar file, so that I can import them during the initialization via `getResourceAsStream(path)`.

Is there a way to import all relevant TTFs and then just call `new Font("Custom Font Name", fontStyle, fontSize);` so that it's used like an installed font (Picture 1), and that it doesn't looks like a derived 'fake' bold font (Picture 2)?

Comment: More than 2 weeks and still no answer :(

Comment: Good question, I'm looking for an answer to this too

Comment: Yes, encountered similar problem. I know it's a bit late but the font family names in Consolas are different right?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what exactly is the problem. You got all your TTF files and you have to import and register them. Following tests use *DejaVu Sans* fonts which are not installed on my system.

---

## Test 1

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("dvs.ttf"));

GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(f);

Font dvs = new Font("DejaVu Sans", Font.PLAIN, 20);
```

Here's an image with plain (`dvs`) and derived **bold** (`dvs.deriveFont(Font.BOLD)`) font.

[image]

## Test 2

```
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("dvs.ttf"));
Font fb = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("dvsb.ttf"));

GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(f);
ge.registerFont(fb);

Font dvs = new Font("DejaVu Sans", Font.PLAIN, 20);
Font dvsb = new Font("DejaVu Sans", Font.BOLD, 20);
```

And here's an image with plain (`dvs`) and truly **bold** (`dvsb`) font.

[image]

You can confirm that correct file is used by looking at `font2DHandle`.

[image]
[image]

---

I also tested *italic* and ***bold italic*** and both worked as well as `Font#createFont(int, InputStream)` method.

Above approach works because fonts are mapped by their full name (e.g. Arial, Arial Bold etc.), so as long as your fonts are correctly named you can register multiple members of one family.