# Registering multiple styles of an external font in java swing

Tags: java, swing, fonts

I want to include a font as a resource file in my deployed application.

To use it in swing, I know that I can import a font like this:

```
InputStream is_regular = Resources.class.getResourceAsStream("Lato-Regular.ttf");
Font regular_font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is_regular);
```

But how can I register also the bold variant, which is stored in a file called "Lato-Bold.ttf"?

I also know that I can access the variant weights via the attributes field. But how do I register these?
The Lato Font comes in 18 different variants such as light, semibold, hairline, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a custom java.awt.Font from a Font family with multiple TTF files? (An example is included)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800886/how-to-import-a-custom-java-awt-font-from-a-font-family-with-multiple-ttf-files)

Comment: I think that solved it!

Answer (score 3):

You write a FontManager.  The solution to almost any Java problem is either a manager or a factory.  Sometimes you need a manager-factory.

One way would be like this.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.annotation.Resources;

public class FontManager {

    public static Font getNormalFont() {
        return getFont("Lato-Regular.ttf");
    }

    public static Font getBoldFont() {
        return getFont("Lato-Bold.ttf");
    }

    private static Font getFont(String fontFileName) {
        InputStream is = Resources.class.getResourceAsStream(fontFileName);
        try {
            return Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

You write a getter method for the 18 variations of your font.

The `return null` at the end of the getFont method can be changed to return a standard font.

If you want to deploy the fonts with your application, you need to copy the font files into a resource folder in your application.  You add the application resource folder to your Java build path (classpath).  This line in the code would change to

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + fontFileName);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.  
If i want to use the standard java methods like `.deriveFont(Font.BOLD)` I have to override the `Font` class to implement such a behaviour?
Using different font styles in a `JLabel` with html, this doesnt work with a custom font, right?

Comment: @trainrobbery: You have to use the Lato-Bold.ttf to get the bold font.  You still have to derive fonts with different point sizes.  You can put all of the derived fonts as getters in your FontManager class.  You cannot use different font styles in a JLabel with HTML.  Swing only recognizes HTML 3.2.  You may need to draw text on a drawing JPanel.

Comment: This manager isn't necessary for the regular italic/bold variants, because once the tff files are registered with the `java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment`, invoking `new Font("Lato", Font.BOLD, 12)` will use the right file automatically. It doesn't seem to work when the font is derived to use a different weight though (Java bug?).